# Adding a shared_ptr to my map throws read access violation

Tags: c++, entity-component-system

So I am working on building a game engine in C++, just for learning purposes. I am trying to follow a Entity Component System and I am having a problem when I add components to my Entity.

In my Entity class I want to hold all the components of that entity in: `std::map<type_index, std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;`

When I add a component I have this method in the .h file of my Entity class:

```
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> 
std::shared_ptr<T> addComponent(TArgs&&... mArgs) {
    std::shared_ptr<T> component(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...)); 
    component->entity = this;
    component->init();

    // This is where the error is being thrown 
    components.emplace(type_index(typeid(*component)), component); 
    return component;
}
```

in the same method I have also done some different things like trying to add components like `components[std::type_index(typeid(*component))] = component;` instead of using emplace and then I have also tried to `std::move` the component into the map.

My exact error is:

```
    Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
    **std::forward<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<std::type_index const ,std::shared_ptr<Component> >,void *> * &>**(...) returned 0x4. occurred
```

Comment: is your type_index within the vector size?

Comment: You have a bug somewhere in your code. Not necessarily in any part of the shown code. Without a [mcve] that anyone else can use to reproduce your crash, exactly, nobody will be able to help you finding the bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Pi - can you explain where you see a vector here, or any kind of useful information? There are no vectors here to be found, anywhere, at least not anywhere in the shown code. Just because something is named "type_index" does not mean that there a vector involved.

Comment: @Pi what do you mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was taking a shot at it. Obviously wrong ;)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even worse, it says map :(